# c++ template constructor initialization

Tags: c++

```
template<class T>
class Node
{
    public:
    Node(Node<T>* next=NULL, T data=T()) : _next(next), _data(data)
    {
    } 
    Node<T>* _next;
    T _data;
};
```

I'm new to c++ template. For default parameters, is `T data = T()` the standard way to do it? Maybe `T data = 0` is ok too?

Comment: `T data;` is fine. You won't want to use `T data = 0;` because you don't know if `T` is an integral type (what if I try to create a `Node<std::string>`?)

Comment: Or maybe T data = 0 would be a reasonable way of enforcing assumptions that T _is_ a numeric type?

Comment: @Keith: Or a pointer.  Or has an implicit conversion from any integral type.  Or has an implicit conversion from any pointer type.  Not a very strong assertion.

Comment: Actually scratch that. It could be a pointer type or anything taking a pointer to construct, such `string`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not "constructor initialization", that's a default parameter.  It allows the caller to provide fewer arguments than the function has, the unspecified arguments will take on the default value.

Another way to do it would be:

```
template<class T>
class Node
{
    public:
    Node(Node<T>* next, T data) : m_next(next), m_data(data) {} 
    Node(Node<T>* next) : m_next(next), m_data() {} 
    Node(void) : m_next(NULL), m_data() {} 

    Node<T>* m_next;
    T m_data;
};
```

Where using fewer than two arguments is also allowed, but calls different constructors (that have *almost* the same behavior).

There are a number of advantages to using separate overloads:

- Doesn't require a copy-constructor, if the `data` parameter is always omitted.
- Doesn't require a default constructor, if the `data` parameter is always provided.

Comment: Any reason not to have the `T data` parameter as `const T&`?

Comment: @Keith: No, not really, I just left it the way it was in stonebird's code because there isn't a compelling reason to change it.

Comment: @Keith if initializing from an rvalue, `const T&` will prevent the initializer being moved in

Comment: @M.M You'd want `m_data(move(data))` for that, otherwise you're just moving in order to make a bonus copy -- `const T&` as Keith suggests causes just one copy consistenty

Answer (score 3):

This really has nothing to do with constructors; what you're seeing is a combination of default function arguments and value-initialization.

The latter is described in the C++03 standard, §8.5/5:

> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> - if T is a class type (clause 9) with a user-declared constructor (12.1), then the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
> - if T is a non-union class type without a user-declared constructor, then every non-static data member and base-class component of T is value-initialized;
> - if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
> - otherwise, the object is zero-initialized

and

> To zero-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> - if T is a scalar type (3.9), the object is set to the value of 0 (zero) converted to T;
> - if T is a non-union class type, each nonstatic data member and each base-class subobject is zero-initialized;
> - if T is a union type, the object’s first named data member89) is zero-initialized;
> - if T is an array type, each element is zero-initialized;
> - if T is a reference type, no initialization is performed.

And lastly, piecing it together, §8.5/7:

> An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., (), shall be value-initialized.